# Can I trigger a subscription event in AWS AppSync from my lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

As the title says I want to trigger a subscription event from my code.

Think about an use case, where a user wants to search the Internet for the cheapest flight. A Lambda function starts scraping popular flight tickets offering websites and with each find it sends a subscription event to an app. Is this case possible to be hosted with AppSync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible with AWS AppSync. A design that comes to mind is:

- App users authenticate with Cognito User Pools.
- Define a mutation for sending events to subscribers. Attach a [Local Resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-local-resolvers.html) to this mutation since the only behavior you want is delivery of a notification. Something like `notify(username: String!)` should work.
- When the Lambda is ready to notify, look up the username of the subscriber and then call `notify` thru that AppSync endpoint.

There are other designs that you can implement but this was the first reasonable one that came to mind for me.

Comment: Hi @Rohan, how does the lambda authenticate to AppSync in this scenario?

Comment: @macbutch ICYMI, there is a good write up on how to use the credentials provided by the role granted to the lambda function to sign an HTTP request to the AppSync endpoint here: https://read.acloud.guru/backend-graphql-how-to-trigger-an-aws-appsync-mutation-from-aws-lambda-eda13ebc96c3

Comment: I found the part of your answer "When the Lambda is ready to notify..." a bit unclear. What I wanted to know was "How do I access appsync from within a lambda", which I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293311/how-to-send-a-graphql-query-to-appsync-from-python . I hope this saves others some time.