# How to send a GraphQL query to AppSync from python?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-appsync

How do we post a GraphQL request through AWS AppSync using boto?

Ultimately I'm trying to mimic a mobile app accessing our stackless/cloudformation stack on AWS, but with python. Not javascript or amplify.

The primary pain point is authentication; I've tried a dozen different ways already.  This the current one, which generates a "401" response with "UnauthorizedException" and "Permission denied", which is actually pretty good considering some of the other messages I've had.  I'm now using the 'aws_requests_auth' library to do the signing part.  I assume it authenticates me using the stored `/.aws/credentials` from my local environment, or does it?

I'm a little confused as to where and how cognito identities and pools will come into it. eg: say I wanted to mimic the sign-up sequence?

Anyways the code looks pretty straightforward; I just don't grok the authentication.

```
from aws_requests_auth.boto_utils import BotoAWSRequestsAuth

APPSYNC_API_KEY = 'inAppsyncSettings'
APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://aaaaaaaaaaaavzbke.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/graphql",
    'x-api-key': APPSYNC_API_KEY,
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
}
query = """{
    GetUserSettingsByEmail(email: "john@washere"){
      items {name, identity_id, invite_code}
    }
}"""


def test_stuff():
    # Use the library to generate auth headers.
    auth = BotoAWSRequestsAuth(
        aws_host='aaaaaaaaaaaavzbke.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
        aws_region='ap-southeast-2',
        aws_service='appsync')

    # Create an http graphql request.
    response = requests.post(
        APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL, 
        json={'query': query}, 
        auth=auth, 
        headers=headers)

    print(response)

# this didn't work:
#    response = requests.post(APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL, data=json.dumps({'query': query}), auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

Yields

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorType" : "UnauthorizedException",
    "message" : "Permission denied"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Can you expand more on which Authentication you have enabled on your AppSync API? It looks like you're using API Key, which doesn't require Boto to make the request. (Boto would help you make an IAM authenticated request.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) supports AWS AppSync since [version 3.0.0rc0](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql/releases/tag/v3.0.0rc0).

It supports queries, mutation and even subscriptions on the realtime endpoint.

The documentation is available [here](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/appsync.html)

Here is an example of a mutation using the API Key authentication:

```py
import asyncio
import os
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
from gql.transport.appsync_auth import AppSyncApiKeyAuthentication

# Uncomment the following lines to enable debug output
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


async def main():

    # Should look like:
    # https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appsync-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/graphql
    url = os.environ.get("AWS_GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT")
    api_key = os.environ.get("AWS_GRAPHQL_API_KEY")

    if url is None or api_key is None:
        print("Missing environment variables")
        sys.exit()

    # Extract host from url
    host = str(urlparse(url).netloc)

    auth = AppSyncApiKeyAuthentication(host=host, api_key=api_key)

    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url=url, auth=auth)

    async with Client(
        transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=False,
    ) as session:

        query = gql(
            """
mutation createMessage($message: String!) {
  createMessage(input: {message: $message}) {
    id
    message
    createdAt
  }
}"""
        )

        variable_values = {"message": "Hello world!"}

        result = await session.execute(query, variable_values=variable_values)
        print(result)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 22):

It's quite simple--once you know. There are some things I didn't appreciate:

1. I've assumed IAM authentication (OpenID appended way below)
   There are a number of ways for appsync to handle authentication. We're using IAM so that's what I need to deal with, yours might be different.
2. Boto doesn't come into it.
   We want to issue a request like any regular punter, they don't use boto, and neither do we.  Trawling the AWS boto docs was a waste of time.
3. Use the **AWS4Auth** library
   We are going to send a *regular* http request to aws, so whilst we can use python *requests* they need to be authenticated--by attaching headers.
   And, of course, AWS auth headers are special and different from all others.
   [You can try to work out how to do it
   yourself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html), or you can go looking for someone else who has already done it: [Aws_requests_auth](https://github.com/davidmuller/aws-requests-auth), the one I started with, probably works just fine, but I have ended up with [AWS4Auth](https://pypi.org/project/requests-aws4auth/).  There are many others of dubious value; none endorsed or provided by Amazon (that I could find).
4. Specify `appsync` as the "service"
   What service are we calling?  I didn't find any examples of anyone doing this anywhere.  All the examples are trivial S3 or EC2 or even EB which left uncertainty. Should we be talking to api-gateway service?  Whatsmore, you **feed this detail into the AWS4Auth routine**, or authentication data.  Obviously, in hindsight, the request is hitting Appsync, so it will be authenticated by Appsync, so specify "appsync" as the *service* when putting together the auth headers.

It comes together as:

```
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

# Use AWS4Auth to sign a requests session
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = AWS4Auth(
    # An AWS 'ACCESS KEY' associated with an IAM user.
    'AKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2A',
    # The 'secret' that goes with the above access key.                    
    'kwWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgEm',    
    # The region you want to access.
    'ap-southeast-2',
    # The service you want to access.
    'appsync'
)
# As found in AWS Appsync under Settings for your endpoint.
APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://nqxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxke'
                           '.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql'
# Use JSON format string for the query. It does not need reformatting.
query = """
    query foo {
        GetUserSettings (
           identity_id: "ap-southeast-2:8xxxxxxb-7xx4-4xx4-8xx0-exxxxxxx2"
        ){ 
           user_name, email, whatever 
}}"""
# Now we can simply post the request...
response = session.request(
    url=APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,
    method='POST',
    json={'query': query}
)
print(response.text)
```

Which yields

```
# Your answer comes as a JSON formatted string in the text attribute, under data. 
{"data":{"GetUserSettings":{"user_name":"0xxxxxxx3-9102-42f0-9874-1xxxxx7dxxx5"}}}
```

## Getting credentials

To get rid of the hardcoded key/secret you can consume the local AWS `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials`, and it is done this way...

```
# Use AWS4Auth to sign a requests session
session = requests.Session()
credentials = boto3.session.Session().get_credentials()
session.auth = AWS4Auth(
    credentials.access_key,
    credentials.secret_key,
    boto3.session.Session().region_name,
    'appsync',
    session_token=credentials.token
)
...<as above>
```

This does seem to respect the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` for assuming different roles.

Note that [STS.get_session_token](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_session_token) is not the way to do it, as it may try to assume a role from a role, depending where it keyword matched the AWS_PROFILE value.  Labels in the `credentials` file will work because the keys are right there, but names found in the `config` file do not work, as that assumes a role already.

### OpenID

In this scenario, all the complexity is transferred to the conversation with the *openid connect* provider.  The hard stuff is all the auth hoops you jump through to get an `access token`, and thence using the `refresh token` to keep it alive.  That is where all the real work lies.

Once you finally have an access token, assuming you have configured the "OpenID Connect" Authorization Mode in appsync, then you can, very simply, drop the access token into the header:

```
response = requests.post(
    url="https://nc3xxxxxxxxxx123456zwjka.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    headers={"Authorization": ACCESS_TOKEN},
    json={'query': "query foo{GetStuff{cat, dog, tree}}"}
)
```

Comment: Since posting [this blog entry has appeared on AWS which provides actual Python code](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-websockets-python/#) for encoding the header (without AWS4Auth) sending a graphql Mutation, and watching subscriptions!  Might be worth a look.

Comment: Has anyone attempted this but received a 401 Client Error as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77617640/request-to-aws-appsync-graphql-endpoint-returns-401-client-error-unauthorized-f?

Answer (score 8):

You can set up an API key on the AppSync end and use the code below.  This works for my case.

```
import requests

# establish a session with requests session
session = requests.Session()

# As found in AWS Appsync under Settings for your endpoint.
APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql'

# setup the query string (optional)
query = """query listItemsQuery {listItemsQuery {items {correlation_id, id, etc}}}"""

# Now we can simply post the request...
response = session.request(
    url=APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,
    method='POST',
    headers={'x-api-key': '<APIKEYFOUNDINAPPSYNCSETTINGS>'},
    json={'query': query}
)

print(response.json()['data'])
```

Comment: By using this, You should be aware of the fact that API_KEY on Appsync is temporary and expires after sometime. I guess you should be updating it then.

Comment: @7bStan Yes, but there is a way to customize when you would like it to expire in the distant future.

Answer (score 3):

Building off Joseph Warda's answer you can use the class below to send AppSync commands.

```py
# fileName: AppSyncLibrary

import requests

class AppSync():
    def __init__(self,data):
        endpoint = data["endpoint"]
        self.APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = endpoint
        self.api_key = data["api_key"]
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def graphql_operation(self,query,input_params):

        response = self.session.request(
            url=self.APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,
            method='POST',
            headers={'x-api-key': self.api_key},
            json={'query': query,'variables':{"input":input_params}}
        )

        return response.json()
```

For example in another file within the same directory:

```py
from AppSyncLibrary import AppSync

APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = {YOUR_APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT}
APPSYNC_API_KEY = {YOUR_API_KEY}

init_params = {"endpoint":APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,"api_key":APPSYNC_API_KEY}

app_sync = AppSync(init_params)

mutation = """mutation CreatePost($input: CreatePostInput!) {
createPost(input: $input) {
  id
  content
 }
}
"""

input_params = {
  "content":"My first post"
}

response = app_sync.graphql_operation(mutation,input_params)

print(response)
```

Note: This requires you to activate API access for your AppSync API. Check this [AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to add a comment due to low rep, but I just want to add that I tried the accepted answer and it didn't work. I was getting an error saying my session_token is invalid. Probably because I was using AWS Lambda.

I got it to work pretty much exactly, but by adding to the session token parameter of the aws4auth object. Here's the full piece:

```
import requests
import os
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

def AppsyncHandler(event, context):

    # These are env vars that are always present in an AWS Lambda function
    # If not using AWS Lambda, you'll need to add them manually to your env.

    access_id = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    secret_key = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    session_token = os.environ.get("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN")
    region = os.environ.get("AWS_REGION")

    # Your AppSync Endpoint
    api_endpoint = os.environ.get("AppsyncConnectionString")
    
    resource = "appsync"
    

    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = AWS4Auth(access_id, 
                            secret_key, 
                            region, 
                            resource, 
                            session_token=session_token)
```

The rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Hope this Helps Everyone

```
import requests
import json
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(".env")


class AppSync(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        endpoint = data["endpoint"]
        self.APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = endpoint
        self.api_key = data["api_key"]
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def graphql_operation(self,query,input_params):

        response = self.session.request(
            url=self.APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,
            method='POST',
            headers={'x-api-key': self.api_key},
            json={'query': query,'variables':{"input":input_params}}
        )

        return response.json()



def main():
    APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL = os.getenv("APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL")
    APPSYNC_API_KEY = os.getenv("APPSYNC_API_KEY")
    init_params = {"endpoint":APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,"api_key":APPSYNC_API_KEY}
    app_sync = AppSync(init_params)

    mutation = """
   query MyQuery {
          getAccountId(id: "5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee58162393") {
            _id
            account_id
            limit
            products
          }
        }
    """

    input_params = {}

    response = app_sync.graphql_operation(mutation,input_params)
    print(json.dumps(response , indent=3))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, here is how you can send a GraphQL request through AppSync ***from within a Lambda function*** using only `botocore`:

```py
# Signing a request using only botocore
from botocore.auth import SigV4Auth
from botocore.awsrequest import AWSRequest
from botocore.credentials import ReadOnlyCredentials
session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
creds = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

# This is where the actual signing takes place
def signed_request(method, url, data=None, params=None, headers=None):
    aws_request = AWSRequest(method=method, url=url, data=data, params=params, headers=headers)
    SigV4Auth(creds, "appsync", "YOUR-REGION").add_auth(request)
    return request(method=method, url=url, headers=dict(aws_request.headers), data=data)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Prepare the query correctly
    key = '...'
    value = '...'
    query = """mutation MyMutation {{
  updateRecord(input: {{
  key: {},
  value: {},
  }}) {{
    key
    value
    createdAt # CAUTION: All the fields
    owner     # present in the schema
    updatedAt # need to be listed here
  }}
}}
""".format(json.dumps(key), json.dumps(results))
...
    # CAUTION: In the url below, add '/graphql' at the end
    url = f"https://YOUR-API-ID.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}
    response = signed_request(method='POST', url=url, data=json.dumps({'query':query}), headers=headers)
```

Pay special attention to the following:

1. Query: quotation marks. You need to make sure that quotation marks are used and escaped correctly.
2. Query: fields. All the fields from the schema need to be listed inside the request.
3. AppSync url. It has to be in the format given above, with '/graphql' at the end.

**NOTE**: In order for the previous code to execute successfully, make sure that:

- The AppSync API has *AWS_IAM* configured as an auth mode.
- The Lambda assumes an IAM role with sufficient permissions to execute the query. Here is an example of a policy attached to this role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "appsync:GraphQL"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:YOUR-REGION:YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID:apis/YOUR-API-ID/types/Query/*",
                "arn:aws:appsync:YOUR-REGION:YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID:apis/YOUR-API-ID/types/Mutation/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```