# Request to AWS AppSync GraphQl endpoint returns 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, graphql, boto3

I'm trying to use PyCognito (AWS Cognito) to authenticate a user and an attached identity pool authenticated role to give permissions to the user to query an AppSync GraphQL endpoint but I'm getting a 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url .

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
from pycognito import Cognito
import boto3
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import requests

user = Cognito(USER_POOL_ID, CLIENT_ID, username=USERNAME)
user.authenticate(password=PASSWORD)
user.check_token()
user.verify_tokens()

boto_session = boto3.Session()            
client = boto_session.client('cognito-identity', region_name=REGION)

identity_id = client.get_id(
    IdentityPoolId=f'{REGION}:{IDENTITY_POOL_ID}',
    Logins={
        f'cognito-idp.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{USER_POOL_ID}': user.id_token
    }
)['IdentityId']

credentials = client.get_credentials_for_identity(
    IdentityId=identity_id,
    Logins={
        f'cognito-idp.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{USER_POOL_ID}': user.id_token
    }
)['Credentials']

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = AWS4Auth(
    credentials["AccessKeyId"],
    credentials["SecretKey"],
    REGION,
    'appsync', 
    session_token=credentials["SessionToken"]
)

response = session.post(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, json={'query': QUERY, 'variables': {'id': user.id_claims["sub"]}})
response.raise_for_status()
```

raises the following exception:

```
401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: ENDPOINT
```

When I perform an `sts.get_caller_identity()` with the logged in credentials, I get the expected authenticated role from IAM.

```
{
    "UserId": "ACCESS_KEY_ID:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
    "Account": "ACCOUNT_ID",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_ID:assumed-role/authRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials"
}
```

I have also added the following inline policy on the above `authRole` to try an blanket solve the permissions issue to no avail.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*",
                "appsync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I originally tried using this as a guide but didn't see anyone else here run into this 401 issue. [How to send a GraphQL query to AppSync from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293311/how-to-send-a-graphql-query-to-appsync-from-python)

Comment: `{USER_POOL_ID`: is the missing `}` a typo in posting the question or actually exists in the code you have tried?

Comment: It exists, accidental syntax error for the example

Comment: What region is this? We don't have that value nor the `GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT` you're using. Temporarily, can you use admin creds for `session.auth = AWS4Auth(...)` and see if that works to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I'm in `us-west-2`, but in the meantime I can try admin creds